# Drupal6 sidebar code?

Tags: theming, 6

I got this Drupal 7 code from a theme and I am trying to convert it to Drupal 6.

#### .info file

```
regions[sidebar_a] = 'Sidebar A'
regions[sidebar_b] = 'Sidebar B'
```

#### Template file

```php
<?php if(isset($variables) && isset($variables['sidebars'])): ?>
  <?php if (isset($variables['sidebars']['left'])): ?>
    <?php foreach($variables['sidebars']['left'] as $value): ?>
      <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_'.$value])): ?>
        <div id="sidebar-<?php echo $value; ?>" class="col-<?php echo $value; ?> sidebar left tb-height-balance tb-region tb-scope tb-sidebar tb-left">
          <?php print render($page['sidebar_'.$value]); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if(isset($variables['sidebars']['right'])): ?>
    <?php foreach($variables['sidebars']['right'] as $value): ?>
      <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_'.$value])): ?>
        <div id="sidebar-<?php echo $value; ?>" class="col-<?php echo $value; ?> sidebar right tb-height-balance tb-region tb-scope tb-sidebar tb-right">
          <?php print render($page['sidebar_'.$value]); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if(isset($variables['sidebars']['hidden'])): ?>
    <?php foreach($variables['sidebars']['hidden'] as $value): ?>
      <?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_'.$value])): ?>
        <div id="sidebar-<?php echo $value; ?>" class="col-<?php echo $value; ?> sidebar right tb-height-balance tb-region tb-scope tb-sidebar tb-right tb-hidden">
          <?php print render($page['sidebar_'.$value]); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where are you adding that code?

Comment: @DavidThomas This code is in page.tpl.php but the code is for d7 as you can see and I am trying to make it work for d6...
This code makes the sidebar in a theme somehow go full length regardless of what the content length is and mine in d6 is not doing that so I'm not sure how I can do that with css either ?

Comment: an easier way to set the sidebar height is with CSS, e.g: #sidebar-left{ min-height: 800px; }

Comment: @DavidThomas I don't want my sidebar to be fixed sized, it should be the same as the article in the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality aside, I think the basic structure for D6 would be:

```
<?php
if(isset($sidebars['left'])):
  foreach($sidebars['left'] as $value):
    if (!empty(${'sidebar_'.$value})): ?>
    <div id="sidebar-<?php echo $value; ?>" class="col-<?php echo $value; ?> sidebar left tb-height-balance tb-region tb-scope tb-sidebar tb-left">
      <?php print ${'sidebar_'.$value}; ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    endif; 
  endforeach; 
endif; ?>
```